# Alinhamento de HTML usando Python

Tags: html, python, python-2.7

Preciso alinhar um **codigo HTML**, em algumas partes ele vem totalmente "bagunçado", exemplo:

```
<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>
```

O html vem só em uma linha, e eu quero que ele fique organizado assim:

```
<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>
<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>
<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>
```

Um exemplo seria esse [site](http://jsbeautifier.org/), ele organiza tudo.
Agora a questão é: Como posso alinhar todo o site usando o **PYTHON 2.7**.
Observei que há uma biblioteca do site [jsbeautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify).

Baixei ela e tentei usar, mais não entendi muito bem o funcionamento.

O meu código baixa o HTML do meu site, em que há uma longa lista. Então o arquivo vem como .HTML

JSBEAUTIFER

```
datafile = file('meusitehtml.html')
import jsbeautifier
res = jsbeautifier.beautify(datafile)
res = jsbeautifier.beautify_file('some_file.js')
```

Não entendi muito bem como posso usar O [jsbeautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify).

**->** Preciso de um exemplo de como posso usar o [jsbeautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)?

Comment: No VS Code vc sonsegue fazer isso tranqualio com o plugin Beautify https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify#overview

Comment: Com o Google Developer Tool vc consegue fazer isso direto no Chrome, se quiser eu posto a resposta com umas imagens ensinando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é simples de fazer usando a biblioteca lxml.

http://lxml.de

Segue um exemplo de código:

```
from lxml import etree, html
documento = html.fromstring('<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>')
html_formatado = etree.tostring(documento, pretty_print=True).decode('utf8')
print(html_formatado)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

content = '<li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li><li><a href="dsadas">dsadaads</a></li>'
soup = bs(content, "html5lib")
prettyHTML = soup.prettify()
```

Imprimindo o resultado

```
print(prettyHTML)

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <li>
   <a href="dsadas">
    dsadaads
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="dsadas">
    dsadaads
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="dsadas">
    dsadaads
   </a>
  </li>
 </body>
</html>
```

Espero que ajude